# Filter data from class array before binding to gridview in .net using c#

Tags: c#

I have a ICollection class LabCollection with an array list.This array list contains another  class LabEntity.LabEntity has property LabID,LabName etc

I am binding icollection class to gridview

```
LabCollection objLabCollection=new LabCollection();

gridview.datasource=objlabCollection
gridview.databind();
```

I have to fillter class before binding to grid with specific LabName. I try this

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource=objlabCollection
bs.Filter = "LabName='CPT'";

gridview.DataSource = bs;
gridview.DataBind();
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+filter+collection&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&client=safari

Answer (score 1):

You have two classes `LabCollection` and `LabEntity`. `LabCollection` contains an `ArrayList` now.

A much better approach will be to change the `LabCollection` class like this. ( I would rather name it `LabCollectionManager` )

```
public class LabCollectionManager()
{

    //.................

    public List<LabEntity> GetAllLabEntities()
    {
        //method that generates a generic list of LabEntity 
    }

    public List<LabEntity> GetLabEntitiesByLabName(string labName)
    {
        return GetAllLabEntities().Where(le => le.LabName == labName).ToList();
    }

    //.................

}
```

Now call it in the code-behind like this

```
var labManager = new LabCollectionManager();
gridview.DataSource = labManager.GetLabEntitiesByLabName("CPT");
gridview.DataBind();
```

Update:

If you wanna persist using ArrayList, change your functions like this

```
public class LabCollectionManager()
{

    //.................

    public ArrayList GetAllLabEntities()
    {
        //method that generates a generic list of LabEntity 
    }

    public ArrayList GetLabEntitiesByLabName(string labName)
    {
        var completeList = GetAllLabEntities();
        var filteredList = new ArrayList(completeList.Cast<LabEntity>()
                                    .Where(le => le.LabName == labName)
                                    ToList());
        return filteredList;
    }

    //.................

}
```

P.S: Not very optimised, but this will help you get started.

Comment: This code  return GetAllLabEntities().Where(le => le.LabName == labName).ToList(); has some error.There id no function where

Comment: whats the return type of your `GetAllLabEntities`? you have to change it from `ArrayList` to `List<LabEntity>`

Answer (score 1):

Sure, as answered by naveen, you need user-defined methods to operate on user-defined data.

```
public IList<LabEntity> GetAllEntities(string filterStr)
{
   var entity=from ds in datasource where ds.labName==filterStr select ds;
   return entity.ToList();
}
```

in which `datasource` is your array list, which also is a list of elements or an array of elements or whatever you would want to state about it.

Also, it's a good practice to have your return type as an interface instead of a concrete class type.